# How to load a custom js file with a controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

If I follow `user_create_path`, the file "views/users/create.js.erb" will be run, if I'm using this code:

**users_controller.br**

```
def create
  #...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

How can I conditionally load different js files?

I'm thinking of something along these lines:

```
def create
  #...
  if User.all.count < 50
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js { create_a.js.erb }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js { create_b.js.erb }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried this? What was the outcome?

Comment: @Beartech Oh, I just wrote that code to show what I was trying to do. Are you saying it might actually work?

Comment: It's just doing what you tell it to, I don't see any glaring reason. But I've never tried it. You might have to use the `render` method, but give it a try. Can't hurt anything. One thing about Ruby and Rails is I find my self just trying things that seem like they should work, and they do!

Comment: @Beartech +1, with Rails, if you are thinking about a functionnality that could be usefull / easy-to-use, there is probably someone who had this need before you and made it a built-in Rails functionnality or a gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should run different js based on a condition?

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js { @users_count = User.all.count }
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @users_count < 50 %>
  alert('a');
<% else %>
  alert('b');
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 ! in addition to that, the `create.js.erb` could just hold the logic (if/else block) and call other files like `render 'create_a.js.erb'`. So `create.js.erb` would be a file holding the logic and rendering the appropriate file according to the logic.